# Different network speeds from servers on same subnet

Tags: networking, centos, performance

I have a pretty strange issue, I'm looking for advice on how I can debug it.

I have two servers (A) and (B) on the same subnet and switch.  Server A->B transfers at a full 12MB/s and vice-versa.

However, to an external site, Server A transfers at 4MB/s while Server B is only transferring at 500KB/s.  Same file, same end server, same outbound route, same transfer method (SCP & HTTP).   There is no rate limiting on our end, iptables is shut down for testing purposes, both hosts are running CentOS 6.

How can I figure out what is causing the speed difference?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with how TCP window interact with the NIC driver.

First, check that TCP window scaling is enabled, issuing `sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling`. If it is not enabled, activate it using `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=1` and retry your test.

If it does not work, you may be in need of manual tuning of TCP parameters. As it can be quite complex, see [here](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-network-tcp-performance-tuning-sysctl) for more information.

As a last resort, if TCP window scaling was enabled and you continue to have bad performance, try disabling it using `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I tried tuning sysctl setting and did get up to ~1.3MB/s.  Still not close to the 4MB/s of the other server though.